# Why can't I enter USART3_IRQHandler?

Tags: stm32

```
#if EN_USART2 
u16 _distance1=0;
u16 distance1=0;

void USART2_Init(u32 bound) {
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART2, ENABLE);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART2_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 3;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 3;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

  USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = bound; 
  USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;                 
  USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;           
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;                
  USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
  USART_Init(USART2, &USART_InitStructure);                 
  USART_ITConfig(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);          
  USART_Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);
}

void USART2_IRQHandler(void){
  u8 a;
  if(USART_GetITStatus(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET){
    a =USART_ReceiveData(USART2);
        if(a!=0xa5) _distance1=(_distance1<<8)|a;
        else
        {
            distance1=_distance1;
            _distance1=0;
        }
  }
}
#endif


#if EN_USART3
u16 _distance2=0;
u16 distance2=0;

void USART3_Init(u32 bound) {
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);        
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3, ENABLE);  

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART3_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 3;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 3;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

  USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = bound;     
  USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b; 
  USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
  USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure);
  USART_ITConfig(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
  USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);
}

void USART3_IRQHandler(void){
  u8 a;
  if(USART_GetITStatus(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET){
    a =USART_ReceiveData(USART3); 
        if(a!=0xa5) _distance2=(_distance2<<8)|a;
        else
        {
            distance2=_distance2;
            _distance2=0;
        }
  }
}
#endif
```

This is part of the code of usart.c. EN_USART2 and EN_USART3 are all 1. main.c is as follows:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "delay.h"
#include "system.h"
#include "usart.h"
// Device header
int main(void)
{
    SystemInit();
    USART1_Init(115200);
    USART2_Init(115200);
    USART3_Init(115200);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("difference: %dmm\r\n",distance1-distance2);
        delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

It runs on STM32F103C8T6. PA2 and PA3 connects to an ultrasound module, and PB10 and PB11 connects to another ultrasound module. I found that the interruption service function of USART2 can be implemented, but that of USART3 cannot. Why is that? USART3 and USART2 are all written similarly. (As for how do I know that USART2 doesn't work: I added printf("p") behind `a =USART_ReceiveData(USART3);`, but I didn't see any "p" on the serial debug window(however, messages printed in main() all displayed well, which means that USART1 is normal).

I searched for the template code, but I can't find anything wrong in my own code.

Comment: " I found that the interruption service function of USART2 can be implemented, but that of USART3 cannot." - Explain?

Comment: adding printf at the begining of USART2_IRQHandler->It prints out;adding printf at the begining of USART3_IRQHandler->it doesn't implement.